# Display 3d object via VR glasses with user interaction

Tags: ios, iphone, virtual-reality

I have a 3D object displayed on the iPhone screen, I need to display it via VR glasses and the user can interact with the object (zoom in/out).

-I need help how doing this using VR glasses without using unity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Unity, then you will have to roll this out mostly on your own. There are some example projects that show how to create basic VR experiences on iOS (including [one I made using SceneKit](https://github.com/timgcarlson/TCCardboardSolarSystem)).

If you want to make something more serious, and are not looking to just experiment, then I'd highly recommend using Unity since you can then use the latest Google Cardboard SDK. This will give you much better results since it will handle all of the camera/view aspects for you.

You can use a [Google Cardboard](https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/) for you headset, at least that is an initial inexpensive option. There is a magnetic "trigger" on the Cardboard that you can use for binary input in you app. [My example project](https://github.com/timgcarlson/TCCardboardSolarSystem) also includes a class that handles input from this trigger by detecting the disruption to the magnetic field around the device's compass. You can use this trigger to handle the zoom in/out.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and explanation that's helped me, the reason for me to not use Unity is that, I use some visualization technique to display the 3D object so all I need is to be able to display the result via VR and allow the user to interact with it. Does I will be able to trigger the user punch in/out move by his hand using google glasses? And one more thing, please could you suggest a model for VR glasses I can use?  Thanks alot.

Comment: There are a bunch of third party vr goggles that you can find on amazon (search ios vr goggles). The least expensive option is likely to be Google Cardboard (https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/). Good luck.